# Spark - How to fetch value from a dataframe column having type binary?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have a scenario, where we are using our custom serializer to serialize POJOs'

In our use-case, we have formed dataframes having one of the column holding these POJOs.

df.printSchema is as below:

```
root
 |-- mykey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- myPojo: binary (nullable = true)
```

When we are trying to fetch values from this dataframe .i.e. running following code:

```
df.foreach((row) => {
val value1 = row.getAs[String]("mykey") --> this works fine
val value2 = row.getAs[MyPojo]("myPojo") --> getting exception here
})
```

we are getting  java.lang.ClassCastException:, when fetching value2.

Any pointers how to resolve this issue?

Thanks
Anuj

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read an object this way from a `Row`. You can only read the data out as `Array[Byte]` and then manually deserialize it.

In theory, Spark's `Dataset[_]` should allow for this by building a custom [Encoder](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Encoder.html) but the Spark implementation is bound to a single subtype right now: `ExpressionEncoder`.

Answer (score 0):

In java Spark version `3.1.2`:

```java
byte[] data = item.getAs("column_name");
```

Just works.